# React-native android Didn't find class "com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.info.ImagePerfDataListener"

Tags: android, react-native

FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.info.ImagePerfDataListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~QD95sJ0ANNQuaa8RuGZCOw==/com.roots.rootsapp-yLZJ1_fvihTZ4to330UwBA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~QD95sJ0ANNQuaa8RuGZCOw==/com.roots.rootsapp-yLZJ1_fvihTZ4to330UwBA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~QD95sJ0ANNQuaa8RuGZCOw==/com.roots.rootsapp-yLZJ1_fvihTZ4to330UwBA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same stack trace running React Native in Android Studio.

What happened to me was that I had just removed all references to Flipper from my Android project but Android Studio for whatever reason was building from a cached copy of MainApplication.java which was initializing Flipper.

I tried running clean build and rebuild in Android Studio but that didn't work, so I just closed it and tried the React Native CLI instead, which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out my short write-up in [facebook/react-native#41937 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/41937#issuecomment-1862698593).
In essence:

> […] [ReactNativeFlipper.kt:14](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blame/1045b225f1a1ab1150b3e8732820c8cecd3e04c2/packages/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/flipper/ReactNativeFlipper.kt#L14) mentions:
>
> ```java
> /**
> * Stub class that does nothing to ease the migration out of Flipper. Users should stop calling
> * `ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper` in their `MainApplication.java` as this class will be
> * removed in React Native 0.75 or future versions.
> */
> ```
>
> And indeed, if the `ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper()` line in
> `MainApplication.java` is commented-out, the issue is resolved.

Hope it works for you.