During operation, the react native 0.74.2 app crashes
07-08 11:33:57.225 1466 2034 E HwDetectorWithState: a: 3 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.pickyassist.tb, PID: 29556 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/drawee/backends/pipeline/info/ImagePerfDataListener; 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at com.pickyassist.tb.ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(ReactNativeFlipper.java:33) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at com.pickyassist.tb.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:77) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1277) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6759) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.info.ImagePerfDataListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~naQufYIKcWeeH3DLvg1o_A==/com.pickyassist.tb-g9y-9VhNskXIsvMdeT0Uhg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~naQufYIKcWeeH3DLvg1o_A==/com.pickyassist.tb-g9y-9VhNskXIsvMdeT0Uhg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~naQufYIKcWeeH3DLvg1o_A==/com.pickyassist.tb-g9y-9VhNskXIsvMdeT0Uhg==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]] 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) 07-08 11:33:58.746 29556 29821 E AndroidRuntime: ... 13 more 07-08 11:33:58.920 426 426 E ClientCache: failed to get buffer, invalid process token 07-08 11:33:58.921 426 426 E ClientCache: failed to get buffer, invalid process token 07-08 11:33:59.354 426 426 E BpTransactionCompletedListener: Failed to transact (-32) 07-08 11:33:59.371 426 426 E BpTransactionCompletedListener: Failed to transact (-32) 07-08 11:33:59.847 586 621 E system_server: updateValue is called with a value {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, which is lower than the previous value {12, 0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 16, 0} 07-08 11:33:59.847 586 621 E system_server: updateValue is called with a value {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, which is lower than the previous value {110, 0, 46, 0, 86, 0, 85, 0} 07-08 11:34:00.708 29839 29932 E chromium: [ERROR:simple_file_enumerator.cc(21)] opendir /data/user/0/com.pickyassist.tb/cache/WebView/Default/HTTP Cache/Code Cache/js: No such file or directory (2) 07-08 11:34:00.708 29839 29919 E chromium: [ERROR:simple_file_enumerator.cc(21)] opendir /data/user/0/com.pickyassist.tb/cache/WebView/Default/HTTP Cache/Code Cache/wasm: No such file or directory (2) 07-08 11:34:00.709 29839 29919 E chromium: [ERROR:simple_index_file.cc(617)] Could not reconstruct index from disk 07-08 11:34:00.709 29839 29932 E chromium: [ERROR:simple_index_file.cc(617)] Could not reconstruct index from disk
ReactNativeFlipper.java-
/**
 * Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
 *
 * <p>This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the LICENSE file in the root
 * directory of this source tree.
 */
package com.pickyassist.tb;

import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.flipper.android.AndroidFlipperClient;
import com.facebook.flipper.android.utils.FlipperUtils;
import com.facebook.flipper.core.FlipperClient;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.crashreporter.CrashReporterPlugin;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.databases.DatabasesFlipperPlugin;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.fresco.FrescoFlipperPlugin;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.inspector.DescriptorMapping;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.inspector.InspectorFlipperPlugin;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.network.FlipperOkhttpInterceptor;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.network.NetworkFlipperPlugin;
import com.facebook.flipper.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.NetworkingModule;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;

/**
 * Class responsible of loading Flipper inside your React Native application. This is the debug
 * flavor of it. Here you can add your own plugins and customize the Flipper setup.
 */
public class ReactNativeFlipper {
  public static void initializeFlipper(Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
    if (FlipperUtils.shouldEnableFlipper(context)) {
      final FlipperClient client = AndroidFlipperClient.getInstance(context);

      client.addPlugin(new InspectorFlipperPlugin(context, DescriptorMapping.withDefaults()));
      client.addPlugin(new DatabasesFlipperPlugin(context));
      client.addPlugin(new SharedPreferencesFlipperPlugin(context));
      client.addPlugin(CrashReporterPlugin.getInstance());

      NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
      NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
          new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
              builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
            }
          });
      client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
      client.start();

      // Fresco Plugin needs to ensure that ImagePipelineFactory is initialized
      // Hence we run if after all native modules have been initialized
      ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
      if (reactContext == null) {
        reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(
            new ReactInstanceEventListener() {
              @Override
              public void onReactContextInitialized(ReactContext reactContext) {
                reactInstanceManager.removeReactInstanceEventListener(this);
                reactContext.runOnNativeModulesQueueThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        client.addPlugin(new FrescoFlipperPlugin());
                      }
                    });
              }
            });
      } else {
        client.addPlugin(new FrescoFlipperPlugin());
      }
    }
  }
}

android/app/build.gradle-
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native-codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/react-native-codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to create four separate APKs instead of one,
 * one for each native architecture. This is useful if you don't
 * use App Bundles (https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/)
 * and want to have separate APKs to upload to the Play Store.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Private function to get the list of Native Architectures you want to build.
 * This reads the value from reactNativeArchitectures in your gradle.properties
 * file and works together with the --active-arch-only flag of react-native run-android.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.pickyassist.tb"
    defaultConfig {
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        applicationId "com.pickyassist.tb"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1124
        versionName "1.1.14"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release{
              if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.5.0'  // or the appropriate version

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
     // Firebase Cloud Messaging (Java)
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    // API Request library
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.125.0'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.125.0'
debugImplementation 'com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.125.0'

    // debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    // debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    //     exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    // }

    // debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.4.0')

    // Add the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'


    // implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

package.json-
{
  "name": "Picky_Assist",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "^11.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.4.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-cookies/cookies": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.2.3",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.3.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.7.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.7.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.27",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.22.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "toggle-switch-react-native": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "Camera",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Microphone",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary",
    "PhotoLibraryAddOnly"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.7",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.74.84",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.74.84",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.84",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/metro-config": "^0.76.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4",
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": {
      "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.0"
    }
  }
}

android/build.gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 26
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

        kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.2'
    }
}

metro.config.js
// /**
//  * Metro configuration for React Native
//  * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
//  *
//  * @format
//  */

// module.exports = {
//   transformer: {
//     getTransformOptions: async () => ({
//       transform: {
//         experimentalImportSupport: false,
//         inlineRequires: true,
//       },
//     }),
//   },
// };
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const {
  // resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
} = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const config = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
    // babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  // resolver: {
  //   assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
  //   sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
  // },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);

babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};


https://stackoverflow.com/a/77685519/9161478
